# Captcha image custom not updating in mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, html

All is working well except image not refreshing while changing source using jquery while trying new captcha, there is always needs to refresh page then image is updating.

CSHTML:

```
<p>
 <img id="captchaimage" src="/User/ShowCaptchaImage" />
 <a href="javascript:;" class="f-captcha" title="refresh captcha"><span class="icon-f-reset"></span><span>Try New Captcha</span></a>
</p>
```

> I am using the Custom Captcha class with inherit the ActionResult. and the ExecuteResult as:

C# :

```
        public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
        {
               // Create image code here , i have implemented.

               //and add response as:
                HttpResponseBase response = context.HttpContext.Response;
                response.ContentType = "image/GF";
                bmp.Save(response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Gif);
                bmp.Dispose();
                g.Dispose();
         }
```

JQUERY:

```
$(document.body).on("click", ".f-captcha", function () {
     $('#captchaimage').attr('src', '/User/ShowCaptchaImage');
});
```

> But i need refresh the page when i am clicking on try new captcha anchor tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use a unique string with img source

```
$(document.body).on("click", ".f-captcha", function () {
      var randLetter =Math.floor(Math.random() * 5854553);
     $('#captchaimage').attr('src', '/User/ShowCaptchaImage?ver='+randLetter);
});
```

Comment: Thanks @ShowStopper to fast response and its working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Hi i struct with same problem but i find solution on net try these these will work for me. 
these can be happen because browser get image from catch memory

```
          $(document).ready(function () {
               $(".f-captcha").click(function () {                  

                   d = new Date();
                   $("#captchaimage").attr("src", "/User/ShowCaptchaImage?" + d.getTime());

               });
           });
```

Comment: Thanks @anuragdeokar, your solution is also working for now.